# Why are proposals to solve issues discouraged during the insights phase (first week)?

Tags: catalyst

The insights phase is held during the first week of a proposal round. You cannot put proposals up.  Only insights can be added.

Insights are described as ideas and submitters are *encouraged not to propose solutions*.  At the end of the first week.  Everybody's Insights are archived and only their author can see them.

Comment: This question seems like it may either be asking for recommendations, be opinion-based, or off-topic entirely. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Close voters: It might not be the case that the answer would be opinion based necessarily.  There may actually be a real reason for this that some people just don't yet know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Catalyst Team identified research that showed an "ideation" phase where participants shared their observations and experiences without proposing solutions led to better results when proposals/solutions were put forwards.

Catalyst has translated this research into their "insights" phase process.